# Debug C# target with command-line arguments in VS Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, debugging

Trying to pass command-line arguments to a VS Code C# debug session.

[Configuring C# debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/csharp/debugger-settings) says

> **Args**
>
> These are the arguments that will be passed to your program.
>
> **Availability**
>
> - launch.json ✔️
> - settings.json ❌
> - launchSettings.json ✔️ as commandLineArgs

I once again find myself bewildered at the inaccuracy of the VS Code settings documentation. It's a lie that `launch.json` supports `args`; attempting to set

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "dotnet",
            "request": "launch",
            "args": "foo"
        }
    ]
}
```

warns *Property `args` is not allowed.* and indeed it's entirely ignored on launch.

If I write in `.vscode/launchSettings.json`

```json
{
    "profiles": {
        "Company-House": {
            "commandName": "Project",
            "targetProject": "${workspaceFolder}/CompanyHouse/CompanyHouse.csproj",
            "executablePath": "${workspaceFolder}/CompanyHouse/bin/Debug/net8.0/CompanyHouse",
            "commandLineArgs": "should-complain, but currently entirely ignored",
        }
    }
}
```

it has no effect at all. As a wild guess, perhaps it isn't loading the profile: but how do I know what profile name to write? This is entirely undocumented. Or perhaps the file is in the wrong path: but then where should it live?

There's a third undocumented option, which is adding to the `.csproj`

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <StartArguments>actually works</StartArguments>
```

Is this really what it takes? How do I get the first or second options working?